# Select(dropdown) options visible text removed but values remain

Tags: theming

I am having a really weird problem that I have been unable to solve except with a javascript workaround/hack that repopulates the values...

screenshot of problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jmp1t.jpg

The exact problem is that many of the select drop-downs on a site, both front-end and backend have the visible values removed. This happened when I migrated the site from dev to live, but I have been unable to track down the cause, I am grasping in the dark a bit for what might cause a weird problem like this. Something I notice from comparing the missing values and the ones that aren't missing is that the missing ones seem to be only numeric and the ones that are unaffected are non-numeric, in fact all non-numeric selects seem to be unaffected and all numeric ones to be affected.

The places I have noticed the problem are:

Front end:

- ubercart checkout page: credit card year

Backend

- Ubercart authorize.net payment settings page: duplicate window
- admin/store/orders/***/payments: date entry: day and year (but not month)
- admin/store/orders/***/packages/new: qty field
- admin/store/products/attributes/*/edit: list position
- admin/store/products/attributes/*/options/1/edit: list position
- admin/store/reports/coupon:  date entry: day and year (but not month)
- admin/store/settings/store: number of decimal places
- admin/store/settings/cart: duration
- admin/store/settings/coupon: line-item weight (but not coupon activation/expiration time, which is semi-numeric: 00:00)
- admin/store/settings/orders/workflow: list position
- admin/store/settings/quotes: list position
- admin/structure/types/manage/article: edit: comments per page
- admin/structure/menu/item/***/edit: weight

Things I have tried to fix the problem:

- disable almost any and all modules, each one at a time. This is difficult because eventually the more you disable the more broken the site becomes, so I have tried both methods: disabling a single one and re-enabling it when it doesn't fix it and disabling a single one at a time, but not re-enabling it before disabling the next...
- re-install the same modules through devel

I am using Drupal 7.23. Link to site: http://cafemam.b.fgqa.net/cart/checkout

also using drupal to firebug (in chrome) and inspecting the form building shows me:

```
 [cc_exp_year] => array (
                     [#type] => [select]
                     [#title] => [Expiration year]
                     [#options] => array (
                         [2013] => []
                         [2014] => []
                         [2015] => []
                         [2016] => []
                         [2017] => []
                         [2018] => []
                         [2019] => []
                         [2020] => []
                         [2021] => []
                         [2022] => []
                         [2023] => []
                         [2024] => []
                         [2025] => []
                         [2026] => []
                         [2027] => []
                         [2028] => []
                         [2029] => []
                         [2030] => []
                         [2031] => []
                         [2032] => []
                         [2033] => []
                     )
```

any other broken selects I inspect the data for are similarly empty.

Comment: how are you *moving* the site? Stuff shouldn't go missing?! Are you using `drush archive-dump` and `drush archive-restore` or an ssh sync? Backup-and-Migrate module?

Comment: the site was cloned onto another spot on the same server to 'move' it, so nothing was really moved. I can't figure out what happened or how to solve it...

Comment: good luck with this. :/

Comment: Thanks, maybe this needs to be posted to a SE site with more traffic, this is a weird problem!